# How to only display folder name instead of path, in textbox from FolderBrowserDialog?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, folderbrowserdialog

I am able to run the codes for my FolderBrowserDialog and it will show me the entire path for the selected folder.

Are there any ways where the text box will only display the folder name instead of the whole path?

Now it is showing "C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\Flight"

I would only want to display the "Flight" folder.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = FBD.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = new DirectoryInfo(FBD.SelectedPath).Name;
    }
}
```

You'll need to make sure you have `using System.IO;` included as well.

Comment: Hi Joshua, Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help! If that answer worked for you be sure to click the checkmark on the left. Thanks!